# Numerical method for second order O

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Here is a question I got to thinking about while reading speculation about the world being discrete. Suppose I want to solve a second order ODE numerically. Let's say $y''+ay'+by =f(x)$ for concreteness. Usually when we solve this equation numerically we will have a value for y and a value for y' at every point we simulate.

Are there any methods that use only a value for $y$ at each point in time?

Intuivitely we might use the approximation $y'' \approx \frac{y(t+h)-2y(t)-y(t-h)}{h^2}$ to turn the differential equation into a diffence equation, but I don't know if that converges as $h$ goes to zero.

Does anyone know if that would give a convergent method, or if there are any other numerial methods that would work using only an approximation to $y$ at each point.

Comment: This is called a finite difference method, currently the most popular should be the Verlet method, applied in quick'n'dirty physics engines. Usually the two direct integrations are less numerically stable than using the first-order system, even with a partitioned method.